# Add a A1 or A2 page in a A4 Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I wanted to know if, by any mean, there is a way to add a A2 page in a A4 Word document ?

I'm using Word 2010

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: The 2010 one . .

Comment: You might get a better response if you tell us what have you tried so far. What happens when you insert it?

Comment: Well I can't insert it because it says the dimension is limited to 55.87 cm. However I can insert an A3 page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum page size in Word (all versions) is 22 inches. For paper larger than 22x22 inches, you can perhaps use PowerPoint or Publisher.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't add the page directly, you can scale everything down as an A3 and specify to print it as an A2 since A sizes are all compatible.  If the printer can handle A2, then just change the target page size.  There might be some issues if you need really high resolution, but A3 to A2 really shouldn't lose too much as long as you setup your document contents to preserve the quality of images.